# Heapsort program does not return the result

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault

I am implementing the Heapsort program in C language which sorts with the binary tree. When I run this program, it is ok until it meets the `heapsort` function in the program. I also try to debug this but it still gets wrong as meeting the `heapsort` function.

As referencing some algorithms on the Internet, I find it similar to my source code but they run correctly, so its really hard for me to find out the errors in my source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 2100
void downheap(int a[], int n, int k)
{
    int i=0;
    int temp = a[0];
    while (k <= n/2)
    {
        i = k + k;
        if(i<n && a[i] <= a[i+1]) i++;
        if(temp < a[i]) break;
        a[k] = a[i]; k = i;
    }
    a[k] = temp;
}
void heapsort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++) downheap(a, n, i);
    while(n>=0)
    {
        j = a[0]; a[0] = a[n]; a[n] = j;
        downheap(a, --n, 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n, a[MAX], i;
    printf("Enter your number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d: ", i), scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    heapsort(a, n-1);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code that I list below:

You should stick to the common convention that n is the number of elements. In your code it is the number of elements minus one which is inconvenient. In this case you would call `heapsort(a, n)`.

In the `heapsort` function, `for(i=0; i<=n; i++) downheap(a, n, i)` should be `for(i=n/2-1; i>=0; i--) downheap(a, n, i)`.

Next, since n is the number of elements in a, the loop should be `while(--n > 0)`. The iteration where n=0 is pointless since it will then swap a[0] with a[0]. Finally you call `downheap(a, n, 0)`.

The function `downheap`, is where you have the biggest problem. The function should compare the element at index i with its two children and store the max of the tree at index i. If a swap with a child occurred, resume donwheap with this child. Your function is completely wrong. Here is a correct implementation.

```
void downheap(int *a, int n, int k){
    int l = 2*k+1, r = 2*k+2, max = k;
    if (l < n && a[l] > a[max])
        max = l;
    if (r < n &d a[r] > a[max])
        max = r;
    if (max != k) {
        int j = a[k]; a[k] = a[max]; a[max] = j;
        downheap(a, n, max);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this code is very different from yours which is completely wrong.

For your convenience, here is the code of the `heapsort` function. That code was not as bad, but still incorrect.

```
void heapsort(int *a, int n){
    int i, j;
    for(i=n/2-1; i>=0; i--)
        downheap(a, n, i);
    while(--n > 0){
        j = a[0]; a[0] = a[n]; a[n] = j;
        downheap(a, n, 0);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Non recursive implementation of downheap:

```
void downheap(int *a, int n, int k){
    while (1) {
        int l = 2*k+1, r = 2*k+2, max = k;
        if (l < n && a[l] > a[max])
            max = l;
        if (r < n &d a[r] > a[max])
            max = r;
        if (max == k)
            break;
        int j = a[k]; a[k] = a[max]; a[max] = j;
        k = max;
    }
}
```

Comment: I disagree about your ``downheap`` function because of 2 reasons. First, it is totally wrong about the binary tree which shows that the kth node has two nodes number (2k)th and (2k+1)th. In your program, it shows that it has (2k+1) and (2k+2)th nodes. Secondly, your source code is not optimized as mines because I use fewer variables and I still get the same result (You can debug this function to see that)

Comment: @HoangNam I’m sorry but you are wrong about the indexes. The array is indexed as this 0,1,2,3,4,5,6. 3 is left child of 1, and 4 is right child of 1. 3 = 2*1+1, 4 = 2*1+2. 5 is left child of 2, 6 is right child of 2. 5=2*2+1 and 6 = 2*2+2. Your downheap doesn’t swap any value and doesn’t propagate the downheap call to childs that have been swapped. Your downheap function does not correctly implement the heapify function as it is usually called. You shouldn’t rely on debugging to validate code correctness because debug is usually performed on one particular use case.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry because I only know about the index from 1 to N, not from 0.

Comment: @HoangNam in C arrays are indexed from 0. When you fill the array, you fill it from 0 to n-1.

Comment: I know about it but, to Heapsort, the book I read say that we should fill from 1 to N-1 because sometimes, we need the ``a[0]`` to store the value which is even higher than ``a[1]`` and really helpful for ``insert`` function of Heapsort in some ways